# Can I flash Android on device with overwritten mmcblk0?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, boot, bootloader, unbricking

Can Android device with fully overwritten `/dev/mmcblk0` (without `/dev/mmcblk0p*` partitions) be still flashed using fastboot? Is it true that overwriting `/dev/mmcblk0` does not remove `/dev/mmcblk0boot*` partitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/dev/mmcblk0` is whole MMC storage chip which includes GUID partition table (GPT) and all partitions. On Android devices some of these eMMC partitions hold bootloaders (like `sbl`, `aboot` on Qualcomm devices) which have hard-coded paths in SoC firmware. Fully overwriting (erasing) such partitions means the SoC won't be able to boot device. Since `fastboot` and other service modes like `odin` are hosted by bootloaders, so those won't be available and the device is considered hard-bricked.

Exceptions are if the device does have BIOS/OpenBIOS/UEFI/ACPI support and is able to discover hardware without DTB and boot initially without depending on bootloaders.
Or if there is a way to re-create partitions and re-write bootloaders (see MTK example in edit section below). Something at even lower level which can communicate directly to SoC e.g. JTAG protocol can be possibly used to bring device back to life. However that requires [special hardware and software](https://www.fonefunshop.com/jtag-emmc-chip-off/) and sometimes desoldering/resoldering or even chipping off flash chip. Still after recovering the device that way, you will have to restore device-specific partitions e.g. the one which contains IMEI.

`/dev/mmcblk0boot*` naming convention is usually used to represent boot area partitions from internal MMC on Linux while `/dev/mmcblk0p*` represents user area partitions or partitions on external SD card. Android `init` enumerates eMMC partitions as `/dev/block/mmcblk0p*` and external SD card partitions as `/dev/block/mmcblk1p*` (as far as I have seen). But the nomenclature may differ for different vendors. Whatever the case is, overwriting a whole flash memory raw block device would erase all partitions on that.

---

**EDIT:**

I just realized you are talking about eMMCs used with development boards, not on Android phones. Latter is somewhat different, it can have 50+ partitions on recent devices. Many of those are vendor-specific closed source signed binary blobs. But the eMMCs used with Linux have a few partitions (not more than [8 per block device by default](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.3/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt#L2442)).

If that's the case, `/dev/mmcblk0boot*` are most probably [separate block devices](https://linux-sunxi.org/Bootable_eMMC) as per [eMMC v4.41](https://www.jedec.org/sites/default/files/Victo_Tsai(1).pdf) standard. So those might have not been erased with user area partitions. Boot partitions are also write-protected by default <sup>([1](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/linux-booting#eMMC_Hardware_Boot_Area_Partitions_ApalisColibri_iMX6_and_ApalisColibri_T30), [2](http://trac.gateworks.com/wiki/MMC#LinuxSupport))</sup>, while Android devices mostly use user area for booting (though vendors can go other way) which is easily erasable. eMMC v4.41 also defines RPMB partition which is also a separate block device (in fact [not a block device](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/97548575bef38abd06690a5a6f6816200c7e77f7) and [not a partition](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/207b652cdbec3f7828251ded2c104eea6d036624)) and shouldn't be deletable.

---

On an Android device with Qualcomm SoC (MSM8953) and Samsung eMMC (`RX1BMB`) and without boot area partitions:

```
~# mmc extcsd read /dev/block/mmcblk0
  Extended CSD rev 1.8 (MMC 5.1)
...
Boot configuration bytes [PARTITION_CONFIG: 0x38]
 User Area Enabled for boot
 No access to boot partition
...
RPMB Size [RPMB_SIZE_MULT]: 0x20
```

Another device with MediaTek SoC (MT8127) and Hynix eMMC (`H8G1e`) does have two boot area partitions and an RPMB. It reports *"Boot Partition 1 enabled"*, so `mmcblk0boot0` contains first stage bootloader ([preloader](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/v2019.10/doc/README.mediatek#L30) or [SPL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31252989/9165920)) while actual `UBOOT` is on user area (`mmcblk0p4`). `mmcblk0boot1` contains device specific information available through `idme print` like MAC address, serial number, unlock code etc. However another SoC (MSM8610) with same eMMC [reports](https://fileemmcne.blogspot.com/2017/12/file-dump-emmc-asus-zenfone-go-x014d.html) *"User area is enabled for boot"*. So this seems to be a vendor-specific thing.

---

Again, since `fastboot` is [implemented](https://github.com/ARM-software/u-boot/blob/master/doc/README.android-fastboot) in U-Boot, it won't be available after erasing `mmcblk0`. On MTK devices, though, Preloader Download Mode (SP Flash Tool) or the even earlier [EDL](http://www.lieberbiber.de/2015/07/04/mediatek-details-partitions-and-preloader/) mode (*"On-chip boot ROM for factory flash programming"*) should still work (if implemented). EDL mode on some MTK ([*Meta Mode*](http://bbs.tecno-mobile.com/forum/rom/97373-how-to-unbrick-soft-and-hard-bricked-mediatek-mtk-android-phone)) and Qcom (QDL/9008 mode; implemented in [PBL](https://www.xda-developers.com/exploit-qualcomm-edl-xiaomi-oneplus-nokia/)/BootROM) devices requires shortening test points on motherboard <sup>([3](https://poormanelectronics.blogspot.com/2016/04/fixing-hard-bricked-mediatek-mt65xx.html?m=1), [4](https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-21791.html))</sup>.

Otherwise the only way to flash partitions is by directly communicating with SoC. `i.MX` SoCs, for instance, provide SDP protocol over USB or UART which [can be used](https://bootlin.com/blog/factory-flashing-with-u-boot-and-fastboot-on-freescale-i-mx6/) to load U-Boot and use `fastboot`.

**NOTE:** Don't confuse Android's [fastboot](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/fastboot/README.md) with eMMC [Fast Boot](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/linux-booting#eMMC_Fast_Boot_Mode_ApalisColibri_iMX6).

---

**RELATED:**

- [Bootloader/BIOS, flashing ROM and correlated risks. Why Android devices are more brickable than PCs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205552/218526)
- [Boot Process: Android vs. Linux](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-boot-process-android-vs-linux-t3785254)

Comment: The naming convention is usually same on all Linux-based devices with eMMC. Internal “mmcblk” (eMMC) is the first mmcblk (`mmcblk0`) and external card is second mmcblk (`mmcblk1`).

Comment: @jiwopene I was talking about `...boot*` vs `...p*`.

Comment: So no `mmcblk0boot*` partitions are present on android devices?

Comment: There can be. See updated answer.

Comment: EDL mode also works on some qualcomm phones (although you may need to disasemble it, and short some test points). Then you might be able to restore the system. See for example [34C3 - eMMC hacking, or: how I fixed long-dead Galaxy S3 phones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OY7OlY0OW2Q) for an interesting talk about reviving phones without eMMC access.

Comment: @JonasCz-ReinstateMonica that's what I wrote: *"EDL mode on some MTK (Meta Mode) and Qcom (QDL/9008 mode; implemented in PBL/BootROM) devices requires shortening test points on motherboard"*. Probably you missed that :) Also on some devices it works without shortening e.g. Xiaomi Redmi Note 4

Comment: Some chipsets will also boot off external storage if it detects one with a proper partition table. The table can be copied/recreated from what was on the device eMMC to a SD card then write the critical partitions like sbl, aboot, etc. This will get you fastboot or download mode loaded off the SD card.

Comment: Referring to the first part on android phones, I think it depends on what mmcblk0 has been overwritten with. You say, "overwriting a whole flash memory raw block device would erase all partitions on that". True, but if you've overwritten mmcblk0 with say a previous backup of the device, then you'll be overwriting with a new GPT layout, ie creating partitions. I think the answer could be more clear by stating that fastboot should work if a proper boot partition is part of what mmcblk0 is overwritten with, even though the first part is not an answer to what was asked.