# What is "rmnet_gsi" USB function?

Tags: usb-connection-mode

I was looking through the `init` files from my boot image and noticed a USB flag labelled `rmnet_gsi` [here](https://github.com/darran-kelinske-fivestars/mkbootimg_tools/blob/761e469c64e852092c21eb841b22bfd061ba03f8/cpay_boot/cpay_unpacked/ramdisk/init.msm.usb.configfs.rc#L90-L91).

What does this setting do?

Example source:

```
on property:sys.usb.config=diag,serial_cdev,rmnet_gsi,adb && property:sys.usb.configfs=1
    start adbd
```

Comment: Rmnet is Qualcomm's modem control and data transfer protocol based on QMI. `rmnet_gsi` is one of the functions of Android USB Composite Gadget driver whcih is configurable through `/sys` or `/config`. The configuration must be related to USB tethering.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Android's [generic USB functions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/interfaces/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r57/usb/gadget/1.0/types.hal#19) (like `adb`, `mtp`, `rndis`), `rmnet_gsi` is a hardware specific USB function which exposes some of your GSM/3G/LTE modem's functionality to PC over USB. Usually this is not something an ordinary user is concerned about.

---

It involves understanding two core concepts:

- [How Android communicates with modem/BP](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225480/218526) (which lives on SoC along with other core components including CPU/AP and RAM) for internet data. Communication with modem/BP occurs e.g. through serial channels (like USB or UART, as [other components](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218346/218526) of SoC do: QDL 9006/9008, EDL, `fastboot` etc.), or by sharing a reserved area of RAM (e.g. SMD or SSM in case of Qualcomm).
- How different USB functions of [Android Composite Gadget driver](https://projects.osmocom.org/projects/quectel-modems/wiki/Android_USB_Gadget) (which is an [extension](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/9047fe43bc6715edbde00f8f4311f83483883879) to Linux kernel's [USB Gadget API](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/)) are used to expose Android in *USB device* mode to a *USB host* like PC. Different USB functions (like UMS, MTP, RNDIS etc.) can be configured and switched using `sysfs` or [`configfs`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/usb/gadget_configfs.html).

On devices with Qualcomm's [MSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualcomm_Snapdragon) SoCs (like USB modems or phones), **RmNet** (Remote Network) is modem's data transfer and control protocol which exposes Ethernet like IP interface as data channel and uses [QMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualcomm_MSM_Interface) as [control protocol](http://trac.gateworks.com/wiki/wireless/modem#ModemControl). Generic Software Interface (**GSI**, which replaced BAM) transports communication with IPA core of the modem. Internet Packet Accelerator (IPA) is an [IP packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_packet) processor which performs better than CPU/AP for this specific purpose.

[IPA/GSI](https://patchwork.kernel.org/cover/10969557/) can be used with different [tethering protocols](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-9.0.0_r0.111/include/linux/ipa_usb.h#16) including RNDIS, RmNet and DIAG/DPL/QDSS. In order to access BP from PC (e.g. to use internet or do some debugging), Android kernel includes USB functions (like `rmnet_gsi`) for these protocols in order to expose them through USB (so that Android device appears like a USB modem). [Proprietary protocols](https://blogs.gnome.org/dcbw/2010/04/15/mobile-broadband-and-qualcomm-proprietary-protocols/) may not be used without vendor provided software. E.g. on Android devices we have RIL and `cnd` - vendor provided daemons - to communicate with BP. However there are open source tools like [QCSuper](https://github.com/P1sec/QCSuper) which can talk [Diag protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29036366/9165920) over `/dev/diag`.

---

**RESOURCES:**

- [Gadget RmNet](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-9.0.0_r0.111/Documentation/usb/gadget_rmnet.txt)
- [Qualcomm MSM specific device drivers](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-9.0.0_r0.111/drivers/platform/msm/Kconfig)
- [Qualcomm Kernel](https://projects.osmocom.org/projects/quectel-modems/wiki/Qualcomm_Kernel)