# How do hackers change (mask) IMEI numbers?

Tags: root-access, custom-roms, magisk, xposed-framework, imei

Recently, I saw a "Google Pixel 3XL" with a seller, and he claimed that its IMEI number had been changed. When I asked, how did he know that? He said this is because of the "Magisk" app installed. Then he verified it through our official country's website and it was an IMEI of another smartphone, "Sharp Aquos r2." He also mentioned that upon factory resetting, the IMEI number will be lost.

So how can the Magisk app change the IMEI number? I think it just masks the IMEI.

Comment: "Magisk indicates that IMEI is changed" is nothing more than a joke. IMEI cannot be changed from AP. You need to have access to BP. Usually it's done through some commands. But the communication protocol is closed source. Either someone from the OEM technical team leaks the information, or it's hacked. Then software are developed and sold in black to change the IMEI and make other low level changes like network unlocking etc. Related answers: [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225480/218526) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217365/218526).

Comment: Related comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248071/can-imei-number-be-changed?noredirect=1#comment333298_248071

Comment: @IrfanLatif what about this website: https://gcprobox.com/ ?