# Why are there 2 boot partition on mediatek devices, both of which contain the same preloader?

Tags: partitions

On Mediatek devices, the same preloader.bin is in mmcblk0boot0 and mmcblk0boot1, why does it need to be in both partitions?

Comment: This is not always the case: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218346/218526. But if the second boot area partition had no use, OEM might have used it for bootloader backup. Did you hash both partitions and they are 100% identical?

Comment: On the link you mentioned, where does it explain by why the preloader needs to be in both partitions? Yes the preloader.bin found in both partitions are identical.

Comment: The link explains that both partitions are not identical. Search the role of `idme print` command on MTK devices.

Comment: Btw bootloader partitions have a backup copy usually e.g. `aboot` and `sbl` on Qualcomm devices. This is to make sure if updating bootloader fails for some reason (or the partition geta corrupted for some other reason, though not very likely), device shouldn't be bricked. So a duplicate bootloader partition isn't strange, and nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Both the preloader BIN files in the mmcblk0boot0 and mmcblk0boot1 partitions are identical. The reason for this is in case the mmcblk0boot0 becomes corrupt, the device is still able to boot up.

Comment: You missed my statement: *"OEM might have used it for bootloader backup"*. So I already agreed with what you are saying. But I'm dead sure that not all MTK devices have preloader (or bootloader) on both boot area partitions. I have physically analyzed more than one devices where raw `mmcblk0boot1` partition contained device specific information like MAC address, serial number etc. `idme print` dumps that information to human readable form.

Comment: When you were analyzing the mmcblk0boot1 partition , did you use sp flash tool to make a dump of that partition?

Comment: Why would one need a special tool just to create partition dump? Why not simply `dd`? // Btw I checked hash of both partitions, ran `strings` on both, watched `strace idme print` running which paths it read, studied somewhat how `/proc/idme/` works. So I have no doubt at all in what I'm saying.

Comment: Very unlikely (0.000001% chance) the preloader files between mmcblk0boot0 and mmcblk0boot1  are not identical. Which mediatek device did you test on?

Comment: May I ask why `0.000001%`? Is this a standard? // The one I tested when writing the answer linked in first comment was Amazon KFFOWI (Ford) tablet.