# How to increase the size of the system partition?

Tags: rom-flashing, internal-storage, custom-roms, twrp

I have an old Google pixel 1 and I was trying to install a GSI but I get this a message on TWRP saying Size of image is larger than target device, so I went to wipe > advanced wipe > selected the system partition > and clicked repair partition and it said that it only has 1.3 GB of space, and the GSI file is 2.3.. Is there a way to increase this partition size ? thanks.

Comment: *"if you don't know it - don't do it."* seriously, messing with partition tables can permanently brick your device

Comment: read the [introduction](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218269) first. then search here for keywords *repartitioning*, *gdisk*, *sgdisk* or *parted*. don't follow any steps, just try to understand. basically read a lot. after few hours go back to the install instructions where you downloaded the ROM and follow the repartitioning tutorial for your device. Be aware don't screw up fastboot - there is no flash tool available for google devices!

Comment: You can do partitioning on Android exactly the same way you do on a Linux machine. The same tools and concepts are used. But it's far more complicated due to many more factors involved. As @alecxs suggested, avoid it if it's avoidable. Android devices are highly [brickable](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205552/218526). Also please note that on recent devices there is [super partition](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/dynamic_partitions). On such devices trying to modify system/vendor partitions is not recommended at all as it gets even more complex, rather impossible.

Comment: Check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZgJgqjsfeM