# What are the causes of an android phone bricking?

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware, frp

I will try to change a firmware of SAMSUNG Galaxy J600FN with a current firmware of J600FNXXU6BSK2 with a new firmware J600GDXU3ARH5. I am changing the firmware to bypass the FRP because methods like Talk back, Inserting/Removing Sim card and HushSMS won't work.

**Questions:**

1. Will this scenario will be suceeding in changing firmware?
2. What are the common causes of the android phone bricking? (Hard/Soft Brick)

Comment: You might wish to consult [these questions](/search?q=[rom-flashing]+brick) – especially [What is actually happening when you hard brick a phone?](/q/122839/16575) – and our [unbricking tag-wiki](/tags/unbricking/info) (follow up to [What does it mean to “brick” your phone?](/q/29741/16575) and [Why is bricking possible?](/q/31893/16575)) // Further, I'd say the [tag:frp] tag doesn't fit on your question (or what does factory-reset protection have to do with bricking the phone?)

Comment: May help: [Bootloader/BIOS, flashing ROM and correlated risks. Why Android devices are more brickable than PCs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205552/218526)

Answer (score 0):

If you are flashing ROM, Common causes could be

1. Wrong ROM
2. Battery Failure (Please make sure it is charged fully or upto 70%)
3. Power Off/ Cancelling process in between.

Please search for the same Model ROM to Upgrade to current version. 
Also in Settings, search for Software Update option before trying anything else.