# How to customise Android or LineageOS build and add own drivers

Tags: lineageos, usb-modem

I am trying to build kinda car computer for my own use. As hardware I am using a [Raspberry Pi CM4](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/compute-module-4/?variant=raspberry-pi-cm4001000).

There is an awesome build by [KonstaKANG](https://konstakang.com/devices/rpi4/LineageOS20/) of LineageOS for Raspberry Pi and it generally is working ok.

There is also an [Automotive version of Android](https://github.com/snappautomotive/firmware-device_snappautomotive_rpi/tree/sa-arpi-12L) (haven't tried it yet) and an other similar more or less successful approaches.

My problem is that I'd like to use an LTE modem ([Sierra Wireless MC7700](https://source.sierrawireless.com/devices/mc-series/mc7700/#sthash.RrQx9qrn.dpbs) miniPCI with an USB adapter) and none of those distros do support it by default.

Am I correct in my assumption that USB at Android isn't working the way it does work on Linux/MacOS/Windows and each device needs to be explicitly supported by the particular Android build.

If so, how can I add own driver and do I need to add it to my custom build or can I compile those drivers for a running instance?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Radek

Comment: Related: [Bootloader/BIOS, flashing ROM and correlated risks. Why Android devices are more brickable than PCs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205072/3573) Creating a driver is non-trivial. If you are still curious about details, you should be aware of the [Android Open Source site](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/about), along with sections of documentation like [Architecture](https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture)

Comment: Thanks @MorrisonChang. Will check it first. Just to be clear: is my assumption correct that Android do not cary such drivers by default?

Comment: All the Android versions you use are custom ROMs, so what drivers are included or not is unknown to us. Note that if you want to use the LTE modem with the default Android cellular system there is besides the driver also the radio interface layer which has to be adapted. IMHO if you are using an Raspberry I wouldn't use a non-official Android version, instead use Raspbian OS. The long term support of Raspbian OS is   extraordinary good, so no need to use Android.

Comment: Honestly more research is required since the Sierra Wireless site does seem to have a [Android RIL](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/ril) [page](https://source.sierrawireless.com/resources/airprime/software/android-ril-latest-software/#sthash.ZVFFRY0F.IbZVjMuX.dpbs), limited to Android 10, however documentation is behind a login and whatever Sierra's license requires.

Comment: Raspbian OS is not an option because I need to have Waze installed and it forces Android. The license isn't a big issue because it is definitely for my personal use. Thanks for all answers so far. I was also considering to use pure Android. Need to configure some machine for it because my Mac has not enough RAM

Comment: Please note that ROM development is off-topic, though I feel some questions on the body are not necessarily development questions but may still need small rewritings so that they can apply more to end-users rather than developers.